# Problem with Script to Synchronize Login on AlwaysON

Tags: sql-server-2014

I'm trying to resolve an issue. I've a two nodes with Always On enabled, I want to synchronize user over the nodes. I see that fantastic script.

https://maq.guru/synchronizing-sql-server-logins-in-an-always-on-availability-group/

Only one problem, when an user SQL have Policy enabled tghi script can't change password on other node.

**Error message:**

> Invoke-Sqlcmd : A HASHED password cannot be set for a login that has CHECK_POLICY turned on.
>   A HASHED password cannot be set for a login that has CHECK_POLICY turned on.
>   At C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\AutoCloneLogins.Or.ps1:343 char:17
>   + ...             Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $Query -ServerInstance $SecondaryRep ...
>   +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], SqlPowerShellSqlExecutionException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand**

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: change the script to create the account on the target machine with CHECK POLICY off, then in a separate command, turn the CHECK POLICY back on.  https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32905714-check-policy-is-a-no-op-with-create-login-pass

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using [dbatools](https://dbatools.io/download/) - [`Sync-DbaAvailabilityGroup`](https://docs.dbatools.io/#Sync-DbaAvailabilityGroup) with `-Exclude` <-- exclude the settings that you dont need to sync.

Honestly, you should sync all e.g. sp_configure, logins, jobs, etc